# How can I generate the smallest sequence of adjacent and distinct numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, graph, numbers

For example, I would like a function that, given the symbols of + or - (ascending and descending), makes the smallest sequence of no more than 8 digits distinct and adjacent numbers

examples of inputs:

```
my_function("---")
output: 4321

my_function("-+-")
output: 2143

my_function("+-+-")
output: 13254
```

as i am trying:

```py
def my_function(sequence):
    result=[]
    values = list(range(1, len(sequence)+2))
    print(values)
    for i in sequence:
        if(i == "-"):
            print(values[-1])
            result.append(values[-1])
            values.pop(-1)
        else:
            result.append(values[0])
            values.pop(0)

    result.append(values[0])
    return result
    
print(my_function("+-+-"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
def my_function(sequence):
    result = []
    sequence = list(sequence)
    values = list(range(1, len(sequence)+2))
    contDescending, contAscending= 0, 0
    last=""
    for i, ordem in enumerate(sequence):
        last = ordem if i == 0 else last
        if(ordem!=last):
            last=ordem
            if(contAscending>0):
                for j in range(contAscending):
                    result.append(values[0])
                    values.pop(0)
            if(contDescending>0):
                for k in range(contDescending):
                    result.append(values[contDescending-k])
                    values.pop(contDescending-k)
            contDescending, contAscending= 0, 0

        contDescending+=1 if ordem == "-" else contDescending
        contAscending+=1 if ordem == "+" else contAscending 

        if(i == len(sequence)-1):
            if(contAscending>0):
                for j in range(contAscending):
                    result.append(values[0])
                    values.pop(0)

            if(contDescending>0):
                for k in range(contDescending):
                    result.append(values[contDescending-k])
                    values.pop(contDescending-k)
            
            contDescending, contAscending= 0, 0
            result.append(values[0])
    return int("".join(map(str, result)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This method is based by a brute-force approach: it computes all permutations of numbers, from `1` to `len('+-+-') + 1` and then check if each consecutive pair satisfy the increasing/decreasing conditions:

`(1, 3, 2, 5, 4)` --> `[('+', 1, 3), ('-', 3, 2), ('+', 2, 5), ('-', 5, 4)]` --> `[True, True, True, True]`. It returns the 1st match.

```
import itertools as it

def my_func(seq):
    for perm in it.permutations(range(1, len(seq)+2)):

        if all(a<b if rel == '+' else a>b for rel, a, b, in zip(seq, perm, perm[1:])):
            return ''.join(map(str, perm))

seqs = ["---", "-+-", "+-+-", "++", '-+-']

print([(seq, my_func(seq)) for seq in seqs])
```

Output

```
[('---', '4321'), ('-+-', '2143'), ('+-+-', '13254'), ('++', '123'), ('-+-', '2143')]
```

Remark: with a recursive approach would be "cleaner"

**EDIT**
to remember the combinatorics nature of the problem you can use `itertools.product` to output all possible orderings

```
n = 4 # amount of order operations
seqs = it.product('+-', repeat=n)

print([(''.join(seq), my_func(seq)) for seq in seqs])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it's not a brute force approach. I forgot to answer myself but I managed to solve it :D you just need to put range of `[0-9]` in an array and with `"--++"` instructions (whatever) and as you get numbers you removes them from the array. I'll put it with an answer, check it out, it's crazy but it works. Thank's for your time.